# Excel Index match text issue

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to reassemble information from different sheet into one, without using multiple pivot tables.
So I created one Pivot table where I will find the main Animal criteria (sheet "Work in progress" ; column C) , and I try to attach the other information with a formula INDEX MATCH.

The information I am seeking to attach to the "Work in progress" sheet, is to find for every "Animal criteria" (which can be found in both sheets "Work in progress" column C, and sheet "Animal analysis" ; column G) the different "classification of animal" (which is for now only in sheet "animal analysis", column O). Warning, their is multiple rows of the same Animal criteria, but with different Animal classification. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aya90.png)

Therefore, in the sheet WORK IN PROGRESS, I wish that my columns:

- E shows "additional requirement" if it is one of the classification found in the sheet Animal criteria ;
- F shows "compliance +" if it is one of the classification found in the sheet Animal criteria ;
- G shows "compliance" if it is one of the classification found in the sheet Animal criteria. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAx1m.png)

I know it doesn't work the way I did it, because on the first Animal criteria, I know that it has only Compliance +, the second has the 3, and the last Additional requirement and compliance.

N.B. I left the initial formula in the sheet to help for the INDEX MATCH because the "Animal criteria" is very long and doesn't work with a "simple" index match or vlookup.